# Remove empty array from object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to remove an array from an object if it's emtpy. I have tried this and it works but obviously it is mutating the original data, which is not really a problem for me. I just wonder whether this is the correct approach.

```js
const data = {
  arr1: [],
  arr2: ['ok'],
  arr3: ['ok']
}

Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (value.length === 0) {
    delete data[key]
  }
})


console.log(data)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: "Correct approach" is asking for an opinion, which is off-topic on Stack Overflow. There is no "correct approach," there are only approaches that work (like yours and several others) and ones that don't.

Comment: _"obviously it is mutating the original data"_ - If you want a "clone" of `data` is this also the case for the arrays in `data`? That would require additional steps.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah I know the shallow copy thing, but I really do not mind the mutation in this case, at thsi point the data has been passed to another module and to remove an emtpy array is not an issue at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've done is one of several approaches that works, which is the objective way of looking at it.

If you wanted an immutable equivalent, you could use `filter` and `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const data = {
    arr1: [],
    arr2: ["ok"],
    arr3: ["ok"]
};

const update = Object.fromEntries(
    [...Object.entries(data)].filter(([_, value]) => value.length !== 0)
);

console.log(update);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or just a good old loop:

```js
const data = {
    arr1: [],
    arr2: ["ok"],
    arr3: ["ok"]
};

const update = {};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    if (value.length) {
        update[key] = value;
    }
}

console.log(update);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

In fact, you can use a good old loop in your original version that modifies the existing object:

```js
const data = {
    arr1: [],
    arr2: ["ok"],
    arr3: ["ok"]
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    if (!value.length) {
        delete data[key];
    }
}

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or even an older loop: ;-)

```js
const data = {
    arr1: [],
    arr2: ["ok"],
    arr3: ["ok"]
};

const hasOwn = Function.prototype.call.bind(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty);
for (const key in data) {
    if (hasOwn(data, key) && !data[key].length) {
        delete data[key];
    }
}

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

(In all of those, you might consider an `Array.isArray` guard.)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this (to avoid editing the original data):

```js
const data = {
  arr1: [],
  arr2: ['ok'],
  arr3: ['ok']
}

let res = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (el[1].length > 0) {
    acc[el[0]] = el[1]
  }
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(res)
```